# Vim quicklist entities at line containing tabs

Tags: vim

I make a quick list in vim in my python plugin. It fails to position cursor in a proper place when there is tabs in a line in a very unpredictable way.

For example, there is a line like this in a file:

```
<Tab>return substitute(a:path, '[\\]\+', '\\\\', "g")
```

And I locate quick fix entity at this line at 's' characters. I have a col 9, but when I hit , vim locates cursor at col 2. How is that? This happens only when there are tabs in the line and quickfix list shows the right position.

Answer (score 2):

The parsing of the quickfix entries is determined by the `'errorformat'` option. This supports two different column meanings (from `:help errorformat`):

> ```
>   %c              column number (finds a number representing character
>                   column of the error, (1 <tab> == 1 character column))
>   %v              virtual column number (finds a number representing
>                   screen column of the error (1 <tab> == 8 screen
>                   columns))
> ```

It looks like your plugin doesn't do this properly; you should raise this issue with the plugin's author.

Comment: Is not errorformat a global option. How can it be set to rid of the error?

Comment: `'errorformat'` is global-local. Different filetypes can set a buffer-specific value.